# Javascript - Chrome: childnodes maximum length

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, child-nodes

Does chrome implies any limitation on the child-node(obtained via innerHTML) data length? I can see that the length restricts to 65536 and the remaining data is pushed as the next index element in the child-node array?

Is there any official documentation to support this?